# How to post an array of ObjectId references to an existing collection in node js

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose, objectid

I am new to Mongodb and nodejs. My questions is with respect to performing an post operation on collection in mongodb that stores ObjectId references to another collection.

Exact Scenario being:

I have set of registered users in the Users document. Similarly, I have set of roles available in the Roles document.

Now, what I am trying to do is post the user with the roles from the Roles document. A user could have multiple roles and hence I want to store all the ObjectId references to the Roles in Users document.

I have the following definition for the Users and Roles document.

```
var roleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    roleId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Roles'
    }
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    Username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 255,
        unique: true
    },
    FirstName: {
        type: String
    },
    LastName: {
        type: String
    },
    Email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 255
    },
    Password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 1024
    },
    Roles: [roleSchema],
    Active: {type: Boolean, default: true},
    SuperUser: {type: Boolean, default: false}
},{
    timestamps: true
});

const rolesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    RoleName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 255,
        unique: true
    },
    Description: {
        type: String
    },
    Active: {type: Boolean, default: true}
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

router.post('/', [auth, admin], async (req, res) => {

  const { error } = validate(req.body); 
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  let user = await User.findOne({ Username: req.body.Username });
  if (user) return res.status(400).send('User with username: ', req.body.Username, 'already exists. Please try with any other username');

  // Begin: Code added to populate Roles in Users document. Look up the roles information in req.body payload

  let rolesArray = {};

  if(req.body.Roles !== null) {

    req.body.Roles.forEach(element => {
      objectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(element);
      const roleInfo = Roles.findById(objectId);
      if (!roleInfo) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Role in Input.');
    });
  }

  console.log('Roles : ', rolesArray);

  user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ['Username', 'FirstName', 'LastName' ,'Email', 'Password', 'Active','SuperUser', 'Roles']));

  rolesArray.forEach(role => {
    console.log('Role in user : ', role);
    user.Roles.push = role;
  });

  // End: Code added to populate Roles in Users document. Look up the roles information in req.body payload

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  user.Password = await bcrypt.hash(user.Password, salt);
  await user.save();

  const token = user.generateAuthToken();
  res.header('x-auth-token', token).send(_.pick(user, ['_id', 'FirstName', 'LastName' ,'Email', 'Roles']));

});
```

I have attached the code for the POST operation but even that is not working.
I can work on the PUT operation if the POST operation is successful.

Despite all my trials, I am not able to understand how to loop through the req.body.Roles to set the ObjectIds in the Users document.

Also, while performing the GET operation, I would like to have the Role Name as well as the RoleID retrieved in response when I query the Users document.

Thanks.

Comment: You appear to be doing so many things wrong here!

Comment: Hi Robert, Yes I believe that is possible as I am new and experimenting. The schema worked fine when I was just updating the User data. However, when I had to reference the roleId as Object array within the User document, I am lost and clueless now. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: You really might want to post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/,  First problem is you aren't building the rolesArray at all (and why is an object?).  And you aren't handling the Roles.findById(objectId) promise.